# Access first value of Illuminate\Support\Collection items

Tags: php, laravel

With this following, I code I can view all the categories but I want to show the subcategories of the first array item.

```
@elseif ($categoriesOptions['cat_display_type'] == 'c_bigIcon_list')
                    
                    @if (isset($categories) and $categories->count() > 0)
                        @foreach($categories as $key => $cat)
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6 f-category">
                                <a href="{{ \App\Helpers\UrlGen::category($cat) }}">
                                    @if (in_array(config('settings.list.show_category_icon'), [2, 6, 7, 8]))
                                        <i class="{{ $cat->icon_class ?? 'fas fa-folder' }}"></i>
                                    @endif
                                    <h6>
                                        {{ $cat->name }}
                                        @if (config('settings.list.count_categories_listings'))
                                            &nbsp;({{ $countPostsByCat->get($cat->id)->total ?? 0 }})
                                        @endif
                                    </h6>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
```

and if I do dd() this. It shows the following result.

```
<?php dd($categories); ?>
```

[image: Result]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your `categories` is a collection of one single category model. Is this what you expected?

Comment: You don't have any sub categories here...

Comment: you want the first item from the Collection?